# Syntantic For in python3

Tags: python, for-loop

How would I write a syntactic sugar of `for` loop in python3. I want print if the number is divisible by two?

```
a = [i for i in range(10) if i % 2 print("It is even")]
```

Answer (score 3):

You aren't trying to build a list; you are just trying to execute code for each element in a sequence. Just use a regular `for` loop.

```
for i in range(10):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print("It is even")
```

Your attempt to (mis)use a list comprehension would be

```
a = [print("It is even") for i in range(10) if i % 2 == 0 ]
```

but this just builds up a list of `None` values (as returned by `print`) for no useful purpose.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But how is in only line

Comment: There's no good way to do this in one line, nor do you *need* to do this in one line.

Comment: Edited both question and answer to translate the Spanish into English here - hope you don't mind.

Comment: Its uselfull. Thanks so much

Comment: For this simple example, you could get down to one line with `for i in range(0, 10, 2): print("It is even")` or `for i in filter(lambda x: x %2, range(10)): print("It is even")`, but I wouldn't recommend either. There is a limit to what you can collapse onto one line with a compound statement.